# Is there a way to go forward in Finder like in a web browser?

Tags: macos, finder, ui, customization, monterey

Sometimes I am using Finder and I want to go back a folder. Then when I'm done doing what I wanted to do in that folder I want to go forward to the subfolder I was previously in. But it seems the **Back/Forward** button doesn't do this. **Back** of course takes you up a directory, which makes sense. But when I go forward, I want to go forward to the folder I was previously in. It seems though, that **Forward** is only for after you've selected a folder to go into. And then it takes you into that one. But if you selected the folder with a mouse, why not just double-click to enter the folder right away? And if you selected the folder with the keyboard, why not just enter it using <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>? I don't know anybody who would click on a folder just to select it, and then use a separate button to enter it.

What's worse - if no folder is selected to go forward to when you click **Forward**, it instead takes you *back!*

[image]

I'm used to going forward and backward through my viewing history in web browsers, so out of habit I sometimes try to go forward in Finder and get sent up a directory instead. I thought the button was buggy, until I realized it's expecting a folder to be selected.

**Just to clarify:** Going forward into a folder that is *selected* is logical. But going back because *no* folder is selected, is illogical. So in that case I would want to be taken forward to the subfolder I was in prior to the current one. Or if I wasn't in any of the subfolders before the current one, I would want the **Forward** button to do nothing (except maybe blink on the click event, as user-feedback). But being sent back up a directory when clicking **Forward** is weird to me. (Is it just me?)

I checked the options in the **Customize Toolbar** menu, but there aren't any alternative navigation buttons for taking you through the folder history. I considered removing the Forward button altogether, so at least I wouldn't accidentally click it, but Forward and Back are inseparable, as a single item. Is there any way to modify the functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> and <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> can used for backward and forward for finder

Comment: Thank you! Yes! When done with the keyboard shortcut, Forward works *exactly* as I would expect. (I wonder why the button doesn't...)